# Prove that $ \sum\nolimits_{n=1}^{ \infty } u_n(x)$ converges uniformly at $[0,1]$, when $u_n(x) = (-1)^n*(1-x)*x^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I can't understand how to prove that
$ \sum\nolimits_{n=1}^{ \infty } u_n(x)$ converges uniformly at $[0,1]$, when $u_n(x) = (-1)^n*(1-x)*x^n$.

I tried using Weierstrass M-test - bounding those functions with a converging series $ \sum M_n$, which will result in $ |u_n(x)| \leq \sum M_n$. But after 1 and 1/2 hours I couldn't find the right usage here.
Would much appreciate help. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please tell us what you did. Just saying that you tried using Weierstrass is not enough.

Comment: Added some content. Thank you Jose!

Comment: First you must find the pointwise limit which is the zero function identically. Then use the M_n test to conclude uniform convergence.

Comment: @LawrenceMano, did not quite understand what you meant on the first half of the sentence. Can you elaborate please?